Split of quantum-computing tag
Our quantum-cryptography tag currently reads:

Quantum cryptography describes the use of quantum mechanical effects to perform cryptographic tasks or to break cryptographic systems. In particular quantum cryptography handles the aspects of quantum communication and quantum computation.

What about splitting it into its two branches:

quantum-computing, about use of quantum computers (making direct use of quantum mechanical effects to achieve operation), in particular for cryptanalysis.
quantum-communication (or perhaps the existing quantum-cryptography), about the use of quantum mechanical effects to securely transfer information without depending on the unproven hardness of mathematical problems (including, quantum key distribution).

That would leave the post-quantum-cryptography tag as is, for cryptography that resists quantum-computing.

Related: Quantum tag reform

Currently I have established the tag quantum-cryptanalysis. We could also go for quantum-computing as a generic term, but then we would still have to specify additional tags to indicate what is meant.
I don't think that combining the tags quantum-computing and cryptanalysis is wrong in any way. However, my personal feeling is that quantum-cryptanalysis serves the purpose fine. If somebody prefers the combination using quantum-computing then propose it so we can vote for it.

I'm not in favor of using quantum-communication instead of quantum-cryptography. There may be other algorithms that become available to perform cryptography using quantum computers.
But more importantly, I think that quantum-cryptography is used more broadly and that the quantum-communication tag will therefore not be used. This is actually OK on the site: we can adjust that ourselves. But it would also mean that questions / answers will not be found, and that we cannot fix that easily. So I'm against it even though I agree that is the better term to use.
